# How to write string to a text file inside an ms sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write some log data about my queries to a text file. I tried lots of code scripts from the internet but they didn't worked. How can I write strings to a text file?

I tried [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) one.

I am sure this was asked for couple times in the past and I saw them but could not find a proper answer for it. Thanks

Comment: Why those examples didnt work? Do you get errors?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour No they just did not write anything to file. No error.

Comment: What log data? What text file format? Show examples of the desired result. This is currently too vague and depends entirely on external resources.

Comment: All those three links go to the same page for me.

Comment: @underscore_d I will just print some times. It will be .txt file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

First of all create the stored procedure rather than alter. see linked below which is used write string to files.

[spWriteStringTofile](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/spWriteStringTofile.txt)

Now before executing we need to allow permission to execute Ole Automation Procedures. In order to do that copy the below code and execute.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Finally execute the below code to store string to file.

```
execute spWriteStringToFile 'This article describes how to fully access the
                             local filesystem from SQL Server. It shows a
                 way of reading and writing data to file, and
                 accessing the details of the server''s
                 filesystem using OLE Automation to access
                 the filesystem object'
                 , 'D:\Demo','test.txt';
```

[image: Screenshot of the created file]
I hope this will help you. If you have any problems or suggestions let me know.

Comment: I tryed this code and I mentioned about it in the question. This does not writes anything to the file. Thanks

Comment: @JollyRoger what do you mean by not writing anything? I have done above changes and saved string to test.txt file without a problem. I saw your question that it didn't write anything to the file. But I did it with the above code. that's why I shared you the screenshot as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it writes nothing.

Comment: @JollyRoger did you follow what i told here? because the mentioned by you had some flaws, I fixed it and then only told you.

Comment: @JollyRoger copy the stored procedure and create it if there is no stored procedure with the name